# Injecting vba macro code into excel using .net

Tags: c#, .net, vba

How can I insert a macro code (from database source) into a known excel file using .net 4

Comment: Do you know how to do this using VBA ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this example:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303871

It's using VB.net but it will give you some direction...

Tim