# Run a VBA Macro against an Excel sheet with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, vba

Is it possible to write a WPF C# application that can load and read a VBA Macro from a separate text file, open an existing Excel workbook, and process the VBA macro against it?

I am NOT trying to convert VBA to C# or generate VBA from C#. The application, VBA Macro text file (the VBA is extracted and saved separately on a text file), and Excel are all written / generated separately by different people.

The application load and read a text file that contains VBA, and open an existing excel file and run the Macro against it either by injecting the macro to excel or even better, leave the workbook without a macro in it.

I have no idea how or where to start, or if that is even possible.  The closet I found on SO is [Injecting vba macro code into excel using .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938825/injecting-vba-macro-code-into-excel-using-net) but doesn't seem to help. I'm looking for any suggestion to get me start and I'll share and update my progress here.

Comment: You could put your VBA into an excel workbook or addin, then load it into excel and call the routine(s) you need to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way to add some VBA from file in VBA (shouldn't be so hard to adapt it to C# but I am not familiar enough to C# syntax):

```
Function Insert_VBACode(ByRef oWB As Workbook)
    Dim oVBP As VBProject   ' VB Project Object
    Dim oVBC As VBComponent ' VB Component Object
    On Error GoTo Err_VBP
    Set oVBP = oWB.VBProject
    Set oVBC = oVBP.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
    oVBC.CodeModule.AddFromFile "c:\VBADUD\Templates\MSample.bas"
    oWB.Application.Run "'" & oWB.name & "'!SayHello"
    oWB.Save
End Function
```

[[Source]](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2008/10/programmatically-add-macro-to-excel.html) (have a look there if you want to add any error handling I've removed here for more readability).
You can also open the workbook instead of taking it as an argument of the function.

And then, you can call your imported macro from C# thanks to this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608613.aspx) from MSDN.